# Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. В коде пропадают цветовые выделения

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-code

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. С++. В коде пропадают цветовые выделения в конкретном файле при его переименовании в обозревателе решений(.cpp или .h). Как включить их обратно и как этого избежать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в VS2015 для этого надо стереть *.db файл, предварительно выйдя из него

Comment: на самом деле если перезапустить VS, то подсветка синтаксиса включается, но если файл опять переименовать то всплывает предупреждение "NulRreferecneException"-Ссылка на объект не указывается на экземпляр объекта. После чего подсветка снова пропадает.

Comment: ну ихняя IntelliSense никогда без ошибок не работала, а *.db удалили? это кэш IntelliSense его надо иногда сбрасывать

Comment: .db не удалял, учту на будущее. Спасибо за инфу. Еще я понял что помогает переоткрывание файла .cpp через "Обозреватель решений", такой вариант меня устроил.

Comment: в VS2017 и VS2019 лучше удалять `.vs` особенно после обновлений. Если воспользуетесь Custom Document Well из Productivity Tools, то по цвету вкладки можно понять как открыт исходник, вероятно просто как файл - без привязки к проекту, поэтому IntelliSense не понимает окружения